# startediting EditorGridPanel after doLayout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a container with an EditorGridPanel. When a feature is added to the panel i execute doLayout to update the container. At this point I wont to put the marker in the first editable column in the new row in the panel with something like

```
grid.startEditing(0,0);
```

If I put this direct after doLayout it fails because the row isnt there, is there any listener i can add so I could be sure the row is there? I cant find anything suitable in EditorGridPanel.

Comment: what version of extjs?  3 or 4, this can make a difference.

Comment: @Reimius: 4 doesn't have a EditorGridPanel. Editing is achieved by adding a plugin

Comment: I've never tried this myself but you could try the `afterlayout` event. It is defined in `Ext.Container` which is a superclass of `EditorGridPanel`. The docs don't mention the event so it might be suppressed.

Comment: Have you tried `viewready` event?

Comment: I've tried Viewready,  and every other event, ended up with doing a setTimeout call to make the startediting execute later, it worked but doesnt feel comfterable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the load event on the store.